# EditText.selectAll() doesnt select text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

First of all, if anything can be better in my question, please let me know, it's my first one here.

I am building an app for android.

I want my users to be able to  enter a time in an `edittext` field quickly. There usually already is a time in there, which should be selected so any input from keyboard will result in it being overwritten, while just hitting "next" (or enter on keyboard" will leave it the way it is and jump to the next field.

For all my fields this works nicely, but for some reason I cannot grasp, the text in this specific field (and its twin) won't get selected no matter what I tried.

I put`android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` in the `res` file, and when that didn't work I also put `v.selectAll()` in its `onFocusChangedListener`.

```
        flighttOutStringField?.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus) {
                with(v as TextInputEditText) {
                    previousText = this.text.toString()
                    v.selectAll()
                }
            } else {
                with(v as TextInputEditText) {
                    val currentText = this.text.toString()
                    if (!(("([01]\\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\\d".toRegex().containsMatchIn(currentText) && currentText.length == 5)
                                || ("([01]\\d|2[0-3])[0-5]\\d".toRegex().containsMatchIn(
                            currentText.padStart(
                                4,
                                '0'
                            )
                        ) && currentText.length <= 4))
                        || (currentText == "")
                    )
                        this.setText(previousText) // not a valid new entry, so no update on flight
                    else {
                        this.setText(
                            if (currentText.length < 5) "${currentText.padStart(
                                4,
                                '0')
                                .slice(0..1)}:${currentText.padStart(4, '0').slice(2..3)}" else currentText)
                        flight = flight.copy (tOutString = "${date?.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)}T${this.text}:00", changed = 1)
                    }
                }

            }
```

updating the "flight" var will refill all fields through its setter.

```xml
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/flighttOutStringWrapper"

                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/flighttOutSelector" android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flightOrigWrapper"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/flighttInStringWrapper">
                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="time"
                                android:ems="10"
                                android:id="@+id/flighttOutStringField"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                                android:hint="@string/timeOut"
                                android:nextFocusForward="@id/flighttInStringField" android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I would think that upon selecting the `TextInputEditText`, all text would be selected, but it isn't.
Then, I thought the `v.selectAll()` would do that for me, but it also doesn't.

Comment: try this editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
v.setOnFocusChangeListener(null) 
v.clearFocus();
v.requestFocus();
v.selectAll()
v.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener)
```

Comment: Thanks for anwsering! However, that sends my app into a continous loop of triggering it's own onFocusChangeListener

Comment: it might do continuous loop because of "I put v.selectAll() in its onFocusChangedListener, as well as android:selectAllOnFocus="true" in the res file"

Comment: No, it just triggers both parts of the onFocusChangedListener (clearFocus() will clear focus, which is what triggers it, then requestfocus() will request it, which will trrigger it again)

Comment: yaaay it works! (I did add `val listener = flighttOutStringField?.onFocusChangeListener` in front of it, just in case somebody else wants to replicate) Thanks! Any idea why this works and the other way didn't?

Comment: If the cursor is displayed, the width of the selection () is 0, you need to hide the cursor first.and call seleteAll() will activate your registered "setOnFocusChangeListener" event.

Comment: Actually, it was something else that worked -_-, it now also works without those lines. I added `if (currentText != previousText) ` around everything below `val currentText = this.text.toString()` and for somereason that fixed it (even though that shouldn't be running as long as it has focus - might be something with a overly enthousiastic password manager)